# Javascript no funciona en mobiles pero en deskup y emulador para mobiles si

Tags: javascript, jquery

Saludos comunidad resulta que tengo [una web de noticias](http://mirandaenloscomentarios.com/) colgada en la internet y hace poco me doy cuenta de que algunos codigos de javascript no estan funcionado en dispositivos mobiles ya sea en android o ios de hecho creo que nunguna function javascript esta  funcionando estas son las principales...

el evento evento **on click**

```
$("#example").on('click', function(){....
```

tapoco **animate**

```
$(".example").animate({......
```

para poder enviar formulario lo tube que hacer cone el evento `submit` por que on `click` no funciona

estubes googleando mi problema y encontre este troso de codigo que supuestamente funciona para dispositivos touch

```
 $("#example").on('click touchstart', function(){....
```

pero tampoco nada, alguien ha tenido este problemita y lo ha resuelto? cualquier ayuda o tips please estoy quedado :/

Comment: Exactamente ¿qué es lo que no funciona en tu sitio? He ingresado a la web que proporcionas (usando un móvil android) y los eventos del menú y botones de redes sociales funcionan. También al hacer clic sobre los card de contenido. Por favor trata de ser más específico. Saludos

Comment: Verifica bien los menus de navigation si funcionan pero el evento on click algunos de los post no por ejemplo trata de darle me gusta a un post y veras que no funciona

Comment: Es lo que te pido, debes ser más específico en tu pregunta, colocar el código de lo que no funciona y da problemas, recuerda repasar [mcve]. Te podemos ayudar si tu pregunta está bien planteada, pero hacerle el debug a tu página no es la idea. Saludos